# SQL Server: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

scenario 1:

I have two tables INFUSION_APP_APPOINTMENT,INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES where 
INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID=INFUSION_APP_APPOINTMENT.ID and i want to find out the INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID's where INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID is same.

for eg. if the INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID = 1 and INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID is 12,15,78, then i want to display all the 
INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID's where INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID =1.
i use below script

```
SELECT INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID,INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID
FROM INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES
GROUP BY INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID,INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID
HAVING COUNT(INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID)>1
```

but it does not gives me any records.

scenario 2:

I am running below script with the intention to get the duplicate records with different INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID's but same INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID.

```
SELECT INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID,INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID,INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.TYPE
FROM INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES
WHERE 
EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM  INFUSION_APP_APPOINTMENT
    WHERE
    INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ENABLE=1 
    AND INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID=INFUSION_APP_APPOINTMENT.ID

    GROUP BY INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID
    HAVING COUNT(INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID)>1
)

ORDER BY INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID;
```

but getting below error

> SQL Error(164): Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one
>   column that is not an outer reference

how to solve it?

i want the only row which has common APPOINTMENT_ID but different n

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+Each+GROUP+BY+expression+must+contain+at+least+one+column+that+is+not+an+outer+reference)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i tried all but if you see my scenario is different. so it will be great if you help me with my concern.

Comment: We don't know your tables. We don't have your data. We only have the vaguest suggestion of *what you're trying to do*, and, apparently, you've read 49 questions and answers and have decided that none of them are applicable to your case? If you truly believe your question contains something unique, then *help us to help you* by editing your question, supplying a lot more information and *highlight* what makes it different.

Comment: @LalitDubey explain what you want, not how you think it can be achieved. Findind duplicates is easy using ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER`. `GROUP BY` has no references, it returns the grouping columns and aggregates

Comment: @LalitDubey why include the `INFUSION_APP_APPOINTMENT`? All the relevant columns seem to come from INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear. Finding duplicates is typically performed using ranking functions like [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This query :

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY APPOINTMENT_ID ORDER BYID) as RN
FROM  INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES
WHERE
    ENABLE=1
```

Will rank notes for the same appointment by ID and return 1, 2, 3 etc starting from the earliest note. `ORDER BY ID DESC` would return 1 for the *latest* note.

This can be used in a subquery or CTE to find the first, last or or duplicate records, eg :

```
with notes as (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY APPOINTMENT_ID ORDER BYID) as RN
    FROM  INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES
    WHERE
        ENABLE=1 
)
select * 
from notes
where RN=1
```

Will return the first note per appointment while :

```
where RN>1
```

Will return only duplicates.

The question doesn't say what should be done with the duplicates though.

If the question is how to return *all* notes from appointments with multiple notes, a subquery can be used to return the `APPOINTMENT_ID`s that have more than one note. There's no need to include the `INFUSION_APP_APPOINTMENT` table though :

```
SELECT *
FROM INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES
where 
    ENABLE=1 AND 
    APPOINTMENT_ID IN ( SELECT APPOINTMENT_ID 
                          FROM  INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES
                          WHERE
                              ENABLE=1 
                          group by APPOINTMENT_ID 
                          having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.ID,INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID,INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.TYPE
FROM INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES
WHERE 
EXISTS (
    SELECT COUNT(B.APPOINTMENT_ID), B.ID
    FROM  INFUSION_APP_APPOINTMENT A
        INNER JOIN INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES B ON B.APPOINTMENT_ID = A.ID
    WHERE
        B.ENABLE=1 
    GROUP BY B.ID
    HAVING COUNT(B.APPOINTMENT_ID)>1
)
ORDER BY INFUSION_APP_NURSE_NOTES.APPOINTMENT_ID;
```

Comment: The original subquery was correlated. This one isn't. I doubt this is the correct fix.

Comment: @LalitDubey again, explain what you want in the question itself. Finding duplicates doesn't need GROUP BY. What do you want to do with those dupicates though and which row is considered the "good" one? Or do you want all of them?

Comment: does this subquery returns value ?